# Do Nirnroots regrow in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Oblivion, Nirnroots were a collectible - there was a finite number of them*, and they did not respawn.

I've been noticing, however, that when I pick Nirnroots in Skyrim, the roots of the plant remain behind. This got me wondering...

Do Nirnroots regrow in Skyrim?

What about the Crimson Nirnroots of Blackreach?

*discounting the respawning food-nirnroot in Frostcrag Spire

Comment: They do regrow even though one character says "Nirnoots are harder as they won't regrow once picked" which is odd.

Comment: ha i still cant make my self use them! Oblivion trained me too well!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nirnroot does indeed grow back and can also be bought from Alchemy stores. It is a lot less rare than in Oblivion. With regards to the Crimson Nirnroots, I am not sure, because I haven't come across them yet. However, I believe they would re-spawn too. (All alchemy Ingredients I have seen so far do.)

EDIT:

I just wanted to confirm that crimson nirnroots do indeed regrow after 15 in game days,
as seen [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Crimson_Nirnroot).

A quick warning: do not pick to many crimson Nirnroots before starting the quest, as it has been reported that this will cause negative progress through the quest.

Comment: The Crimson Nirnroots are a quest item, so I don't think they'd respawn.

Comment: @Tristan true but what if somone goes and grabs them all anmd uses them in a potion? they are stronger then nirnroot makeing them perfect for potion making.

Comment: i hope the crimson nirnroots respawn after so long..i accidentally used a few of em in potions without thinking and i really dont wanna have to restart my game

Comment: @Jeremy as i said in the question after 15 days they will respawn/regrow

Comment: I am confirming they do grow back after 15 days. Also, be careful not to pick too many until the quest line tells you to. I picked 13 of them before i was supposed to and they counted negatively toward my progress (-13/30) …PS3 version.

Comment: @Andrew that has got to be a major glitch, ill add that to the answer =)

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm they grow back after 15 days also. I'm using the PS3 version and picked about 20 of them before doing the related quest. It does give you a negative number if you try dropping them and picking them back up. So, I was forced to wait 15 days to pick a total of 50 of them.