# What happens if you kill too many bunnies in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I noticed the other day they take stats on bunnies you've slain. Has anyone come across something strange when killing too many (like the mad cow thing in Diablo 2). Or does it help boost archery quickly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope. Skyrim just tracks these statistics for fun.

It also tracks "Nirnroots found" despite there being an infinite number of nirnroots in the game.

Comment: Are there really infinite Nirnroots?  I thought they didn't re-grow?  (Pretty sure an NPC told me.)

Comment: @Iszi the NPC's dialog was just never updated. See here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38349/do-nirnroots-regrow-in-skyrim

Comment: Oh.  Good to know!  +1 then.  Thanks!

Comment: I hope they add some cool upgrade for it later. For now, I will keep my count at 0.

Comment: I only kill bunnies so I can take their souls.

Comment: @Iszi Nirnroots did not regrow in Oblivion, but they do in Skyrim.